# Unable to find xpath "/html - Capybara

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

I created tests for my rails application using `Capybara`. 
I have one failing test without any idea how to fix.

Failures:

```
1) ManageController ManageController check user login to manage admin success
     Failure/Error: page.should have_content("Login")
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       ****Unable to find xpath "/html"****
```

Code:

```
describe "POST perform_login" do
  it ("check user login to manage admin success") do
    visit('/manage')
    page.should have_content("Login")
    fill_in('email' , {:with=> 'moshe.tini@conduit.com'})
    fill_in('password', {:with=>'1234'})
    button_link 'submit_login'
    page.should have_content("Fake Login")
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you post your actual code for the test in question?

Comment: Sounds like the page itself is missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your code in for "login"?

Here's an example...
I went to google and searched "San francisco" and inspected the first link.

The link has a structure like this:

```
<h3 class="r">
  <a href="/link">
```

In this case, I'd just do:

```
page.should have_selector('.r a')
```

If you're looking for a certain text within the url, you could then do:

```
url_text = page.find('.r a').text
url_text.should include("foo")
```